# Чи правильно утворено слово "атошник"?

Tags: словотворення

Дуже часто в різних статтях та по телебаченню зустрічаю слово «*атошник*». Але, за правилами словотвору, якщо мені не зраджує пам’ять, потрібно використовувати суфікс -*ець* для утворення нових слів із абревіатур. То як правильно все ж таки: "*атошник*" чи "*атовець*"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Це приклад кальки з російської мови, адже суфікс в -ник (найпоширенішим прикладом є "ГАИшник"). В українській мові ж АТОвець.

Про це говорить Олександр Авраменко в [експрес-уроці](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=REH0v0p11P8) Сніданку з 1+1.

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Наші правила якості дещо відрізняються від того, що можна побачити на мовних форумах і блоґах. Необґрунтовані відповіді базуються лише на думці їхнього автора і тому викликають хвилю диспутів і заперечень. А якісні відповіді ґрунтуються на якісних джерелах: словниках, поважних сайтах тощо. Будь ласка, перегляньте сторінки [tour], [answer] а також [«Якими мають бути гарні відповіді»](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/). Ви завжди можете виправити відповідь, зробивши її більш аргументованою. Для цього натисніть [edit].